# Neither onNext, nor onError is called when Angular HttpClient POST receives in 500

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I am observing something that I cannot see/explain. I did talk to a second pair of eyes and did my due diligence googling. What am I missing - as the title says, onNext and onError aren't called, but onComplete is when back end returns HTTP500 (endpoint throws 500 for the purpose of testing angular error handling). Why?

Service:

```
delete(item: Item): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.url("delete"), item, { headers: this.header });
}
```

Component:

```
this.itemDataService.delete(this.item)
            .subscribe(
                () => {
                    alert("result");
                    ..;
                },
                err => {
                    alert("Error");
                },
                () => {
                    alert("complete");
                    ...;
                }
            );
```

Comment: do you have an interceptor somewhere swallowing your errors? is that the angular http client?

Comment: That was it :-) You can go ahead and add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably have an interceptor swallowing your errors somewhere.. only way this could happen if that's the native http client.

Comment: Correct, this was the angular HttpClient